# calling non-const function on non-const member in const function

Tags: c++, g++, constants, member-functions, function-qualifier

The member is non const, and the member's member function is non const, when it is called on a const member function, it will generate an error, complains about:

```
error: passing 'const foo' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

code:

```
// this class is in library code  i cannot modify it
class CWork {
public:
    const string work(const string& args) { // non const
        ...
        return "work";
    }
};
// this is my code i can modify it 
class CObject {
private:
    CWork m_work; // not const
public:
    const string get_work(const string& args) const { // const member function
        return m_work.work(args);  // error here
    }
};
```

Why is this and how to fix this?
Compiler is g++ 5.3.1.

Comment: sorry, the get_work is a const function in which it fails.

Comment: In a const member `*this` is const. So all of its member  data is too...

Comment: `m_work` **is** `const` inside `get_work`

Comment: lol why all the down voting, i ask because i met this problem

Comment: because first you posted wrong code which was unrelated to the error and now its rather unclear what is the question. You cannot call a non const method on a `const` object and thats what the error tells you...

Comment: i already fixed my code, m_work is non-const as you see.

Comment: no i dont see it. `m_work` **is** `const` in `get_work`. And quoting a different comment: "In a const member *this is const. So all of its member data is too..."

Comment: maybe there can be an answer if you explain why you think this should work. or simply make `work` `const` too, there is no reason to make it non-const

Comment: it's in library i cannot change it.

Comment: then please add this to the question, it will limit what can be an answer

Comment: btw your error still does not match the code. there is no `foo`. Yes, nitpicking, but details do matter ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a `const` method the object (`*this`) and hence all its members are `const`. Think about it, if this wasnt the case then an object being `const` would not mean anything.

Thus `m_work` is `const` inside `get_work` and you can only call `const` methods on it.

Make `work` also a `const` method. There is no apparent reason to make it not `const` and by default you should make methods `const`. Only when you need to modify the object make them non-`const`.

> it's in library i cannot change it.

In that case you are out of luck. You can only make `get_work` non const too, because `work` seems to modify `m_work` hence modifies your `CObject` which you cannot do in a `const` method.