# const function calling non-const function allowed in other class but not in same class?

Tags: c++, oop, delegates, c++17

Why is it that `get_controlState2` is fine being *const* but `get_controlState` gives error `passing 'const Main' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`?

```
#include <iostream>

class Main {
public:
    int getData() { return 123; } // Actually returns a mutable object

    int get_controlState() const {
        return this->getData(); // Error
    }
};

class Controller {
public:
    Controller(Main* pMain) : pMain{pMain} { }
    
    int get_controlState2() const {
        return pMain->getData(); // Fine
    }
    
private:
    Main* pMain;
};

int main() {
    Main main;
    Controller controller{&main};

    std::cout << main.get_controlState() << std::endl;
    std::cout << controller.get_controlState2() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/5xousuHcDdN

This is very similar to [calling non-const function on non-const member in const function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706780/calling-non-const-function-on-non-const-member-in-const-function), but not exact. He has a library function that *could* be const but isn't because they cannot change it. In my case it returns a mutable object which is only read out, **but works in some circumstances**

His question is answered with "in a const function all members are const too", but this seems to contradict `get_controlState2`.

What I'm trying to do is remove the *delegate* from Controller and put the function in Main instead.

Comment: In `Controller::get_controlState2() const`, your pointer `pMain` is `const`, but `*pMain` is **not** `const`.  A _const pointer to something_ is not the same as a _pointer to something that's const_.

Comment: Inside a `const` member function the type of `this` is `const *`.

Comment: @DrewDormann that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

Your function `int Main::get_data()` is **not** `const`, and therefore can **not** be called from a `const Main`.

*You seem to understand that.*

Your definition of `Main::get_controlState()` is `const`, so it operates on a `const Main`, so you get an error:

```
int get_controlState() const {
    return this->getData(); // Error
}
```

Your definition of `Controller::get_controlState()` operates on a `Main` that is **not `const`**. so it compiles.

```
int get_controlState2() const {
    return pMain->getData(); // Fine
}
```

The member function is const, which makes member variable `pMain` `const`.  It's a const pointer.  But that does not make the object it points to `const`.

A *const pointer to something* is not the same as a *pointer to something that's const*.

Comment: You're right. I can even add a statement that *mutates* `pMain` inside the const function. This is totally crazy, and may I add, DANGEROUS. Why is a const method allowed to change state? Shouldn't const be a *protective* construct to prevent programmers from accidentally modifying state? This goes straight against the 'clean code' practice.

Comment: That's not correct - you can not mutate `pMain` in a `const` member function.  Try `pMain = nullptr;` in your const member function.  It will not compile, because you are trying to modify `pMain`.  You can, however, modify variables that are not members of the class, such as `Main main;`.

Comment: I phrased that wrong. When I say I mutate `pMain`, I meant the object. Otherwise I'd say 'changes pMain'